Connecting to Windows host by disabling CredSSP with enablecredsspsupport:i:0
I have a Windows host in Active Directory domain factory.com.
I tried to logon to another Windows host in   Active Directory domain lab.com. An authentication dialog appeared, but logon failed due to:

The system administrator has limited the computers you can log on with. Try logging on at a different computer. If the problem continues, contact your system administrator or technical support.

I saved the connection as default.rdp file, then
added the following line:
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
I was then able to logon to the host.

Why could I not connect to the target PC for first time?

Was it because of permissions from factory.com or lab.com Active Directory?

Why was I able to logon after adding enablecredsspsupport:i:0?



"When this line is present, you do not have to provide credentials before you establish a remote desktop connection."
That means you receive the RDP session window with a logon dialog, presumably for the computer you are authorized to logon to.
Without this, the authentication occurs before, presumably against the host that you are authenticating against using network level authentication (NLA) presenting a client host name that isn't authorized.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-connection-6-prompts-credentials
Note that this should fail for hosts that require NLA to connect.
